# Accessing the Router Web interface via the internet (D-Link 2740U)

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I'm using port forwarding on my home router (D-Link 2740u) so that it forwards incoming port 80 requests to a raspberry PI hosting a simple page that links to various other parts of my network.

On that page it links right now to :

```
an outside camera on port 2501
an inside camera on port 2502
```

I would also like to link to the router's web interface itself on port (2503), the problem comes in while trying to set up the port forwarding. The router detects it's own IP address and just refuses to allow it to port forward 2503 (or any other port) to port 80 on the router.

Example: I want the "landing page" (on the Raspberry Pi) to have a link: mySubdomain.duckdns.org:2500 be forwarded to 192.168.0.1:80 however, when I try add it, it will not accept the router's address

Is there any way around this irritation? or am I wasting my time?

Another thought I just had would be to open all ports through the router (not quite sure how to do this though), use the Pi as a firewall to the rest of the network and configure IP Tables there, but I've had it from many sources that using the Pi like that is a really bad idea.

I've tried to set the router's IP address to something else, and set up port forwarding to what the router's IP address Should/Will be, and then change the router's IP address back, but then the line from the port forwarding page has been deleted.

Any and all help would be appreciated

-EDIT-
No "Remote Management" section :-(
and can't post the pic because i don't have 10 reputation. However, be that as it may, you can see the screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: Port forwarding isn't intended to be used in that matter, which is why the router is preventing you from doing it. Many routers that have external web access to the router interface allow you to specify the port it runs on so that method should be used instead.

Comment: thanks @qasdfdsaq, that makes loads of sense. It's a pity that they automatically assume that the end-user is an idiot (*fair enough, usually they're right), but a god-mode would be nice. It's a good idea to do the remote admin though... I'll check it out when I get home...

Comment: Even with 'God mode' it's not really trivial. Nonetheless a quick look at the manual posted by MrStatic suggests the settings would be found on page 66 (Remote Access). There doesn't appear to be a setting to select the port, but there is a protocol setting which may help - the manual doesn't state what options are behind there.